# using WinJS.xhr to post variables to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

Am trying to create a login page for my windows 8 app, am using Html5 and javascript.. so have tried to use winjs.xhr to post what is in the textboxes  as variables to a specific url which is a php script so this is my example of the url "http://example.com/api/username=username&password=password" am using winjs.xhr to post these variables to the url but am not getting any response even in the console.log

this is my code

```
<script>
function handlelogin(){
    document.getElementById("box").onsubmit = function(){
        if(document.getElementById("email_address").value ==""){
            document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML= "Please Provide Your Email Address";
            return false;
        }else{
            var email_address = document.getElementById("email_address");
            var password = document.getElementById("password");
            var formparams = "?username=" + email_address.value + "&password=" + password.value;
            document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "";
            WinJS.xhr({type: "POST",
                        url: "http://example.com/api/",
                        data: formparams,
                        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
                        }).then(
                            function (success) {
                                console.log(success.statusText);
                                if(success == 1703){
                                    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("home.html");
                                }
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        );
        }
    };
}
window.onload = function () {
    handlelogin();
}
</script>


<form id="box" method="post" name="loginform">
            <p>Email address</p>
            <div class="email_address"><input type="text" id="email_address" /></div>
            <p>Password</p>
            <div class="password"><input type="password" id="password" /></div>
            <p><span id="errormessage"></span></p>
            <div class="button"><input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign In"/></div>
            <p>ForgotPassword?</p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually don't mean to have the url in your WinJS.xhr request include the form parameters a la `{ type: 'Post', url: 'http://example.com/api/" + formparams, headers: ... }` ?

Comment: did u try puttling breakpoint and debug? though there are other issues with the code - request do reach example.com and a 200 response is there.

Answer (score 0):

First - don't use a submit button. Use a input type="button". No submit required, you are simply reading the values on the page.

Second - attach the event handler for the button's click event. Doing this 'onload' for the window isn't the right place.

Third - don't use 'onsubmit' for your 'box' element. There is no form submission going on here. There shouldn't usually be a form submit in WinJS - that's for a browser posting the page to the server. You already are POSTing your data. See the updated code:

I highly recommend putting ALL javascript into separate files, as you'll get bytecode optimization that way. Inline Javascript isn't optimized for the next load. A common way you could do this is include the onload code below (where I assign onclick) in your js file like so

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
  ..
  ..
  ..

   args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
     document.getElementById("login").onclick = handlelogin;
  }));

  ..
  ..
  }
};
```

But the answer directly for your question above is:

```
<script>
function handlelogin() {
    if (document.getElementById("email_address").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "Please Provide Your Email Address";
        return false;
    } else {
        var email_address = document.getElementById("email_address");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        var formparams = "?username=" + email_address.value + "&password=" + password.value;
        document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "";
        WinJS.xhr({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://example.com/api/&quot;,
            data: formparams,
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
        }).then(
            function (success) {
                console.log(success.statusText);
                if (success == 1703) {
                    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("home.html");
                }
            },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("login").onclick = handlelogin;
};
</script>

Check out some of the sessions in App Builder where they discuss JavaScript projects http://aka.ms/stackbuilder